# Illegal character: U+0000 This error is pinned at the closing bracket of class at end

Tags: android-studio

This class is working fine in one project but when I copy this class to another project.This error occurs at the end of class.I commented the whole class but still it occurs at the end tho there isn't any code at that place.

Comment: Sounds like an invisible null character at the end of the file

Comment: I removed the space from class and commented the rest code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created new java class and copied whole code and pasted it in new class.I removed extra space etc and this worked for me...

Answer (score 1):

Look at the bottom right part of your Android Studio window:

Just click the appropriate dropdown menu (encoding: UTF-8, windows-1252, US-ASCII ...) and try different encoding, UTF-8 should work.

Comment: File->Invalidate chaces / restart maybe this will help